# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' error when using Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im using the Zend Framework v1.11.0 on a Windows machine running the Xampp 1.7.1 package.My project directory structure is as follows.

```
/
|- /data
| |- /logs
| |- /uploaded-files
| |- /tmp
|- /htdocs
|- /include
| |- /Controllers
| |- /Zend
|- /templates
```

I have the following code in my index.php located in htdocs :

```
<?php

    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
    Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

    $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $controller->setControllerDirectory('../include/Controllers');
    $controller->dispatch();

?>
```

The error i get is as follows :

**Notice: Zend_Loader::Zend_Loader::registerAutoload is deprecated as of 1.8.0 and will be removed with 2.0.0; use Zend_Loader_Autoloader instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Loader.php on line 266**

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace:**

**#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))**

**#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\htdocs\index.php(8): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()**

**#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 248**

My .htaccess file located in myproject/htdocs :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

In my apache httpd.conf i have the following VirtualHost defined:

```
<VirtualHost myproject:80>
    ServerName myproject
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/htdocs"
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/htdocs">
        AllowOverride None
        Options All
    </Directory>
    php_value include_path ".;c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/include;c:/xampp/php/PEAR"
    php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_value register_globals off
</VirtualHost>
```

What could be going wrong here ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: why you don't use the regular index.php file that comes with zend tool

Answer (score 2):

first of all ;

```
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

is deprecated and that why you get the first notice

```
Notice: Zend_Loader::Zend_Loader::registerAutoload is deprecated as of 1.8.0 and will be removed with 2.0.0; use Zend_Loader_Autoloader instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Loader.php on line 266
```

in your case your application doesn't know what is default controller name and its default ac tion 
it throw an error 
and the error handler take the its place and again your front controller tried to locate the error controller and it doesn't find it as well 
so it show you this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\include\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace:
```

okay last : 
how do i fix if i would be in charge :

1- re-mange the application structure to be like the default ZF file structure
2- you can try to set the default controller name and action name , consult the docs or 
navigate to Zend/Controller/Front.php 
and you would find functions like

```
public function setDefaultAction($action)
    {
        $dispatcher = $this->getDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultAction($action);
        return $this;
    }

 public function setDefaultAction($action)
    {
        $dispatcher = $this->getDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultAction($action);
        return $this;
    }
```

and many other setters functions

and don't forget to take a deep look @ ZF [flowchart](http://www.slideshare.net/polleywong/zend-framework-dispatch-workflow)
http://devzone.zend.com/article/4601

i hope that help you

Answer (score 1):

The message *Invalid controller specified (error)*, means that the dispatcher is looking for a controller class named `ErrorController` but cannot find it.

The `ErrorController` is usually called when the `throwExceptions` flag is set to *false* in Zend_Controller_Front. When that is the case, thrown exceptions will be aggregated and forwarded to the *ErrorController* class. This is a feature supplied by the *ErrorHandler* plugin: a class named `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler`.

In short, there is probably something in your code that is throwing an exception, but since you don't have an error controller, the dispatcher fails. Changing the `throwExceptions` flag in the front controller, creating the error controller, or disabling the plugin should allow you to see where the actual error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late, this may be useful for some one else who encountered this error like me.

For first error: replace this code.

```
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

with this one

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

and change your directory structure a bit and use following code 
make a file `IndexController.php` in `index` folder

```
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller->setDefaultModule('index');
$controller->addModuleDirectory('PATH_TO_MODULES')->dispatch();
```

instead of using this

```
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller->setControllerDirectory('../include/Controllers');
$controller->dispatch();
```

your director structure look like this

```
application
   modules
       index
          controllers
              IndexController.php
          views
```